# Звонкие и глухие согласные

Tags: фонетика

В каких словах первый звук звонкий, а в каких — глухой?
**Шапка, санки, бак, флаги, круг, луч, хлеб, глаз, нос, звук, волк, рот, крыса, парта.**

Answer (score 2):

О глухих и звонких согласных звуках можно почитать здесь:

http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm#6_1

=====================================

> Шапка Санки Бак Флаги Круг Луч Хлеб
>   Глаз Нос Звук Волк Рот Крыса Парта

ПОДСКАЗКА: из 14 имеющихся в перечне слов ровно половина -- со звонким первым звуком.

Ещё одна подсказка (из учебника Литневской):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

А еще есть предложение-подсказка, в котором все согласные глухие: Стёпка Фец, хочешь щец? Но при этом надо помнить об озвончении и оглушении.